# Print out the letter E made of asterisks - My program works, but I don't understand why

Tags: java, nested-loops

I'm a beginner programmer and taking an intro to Java class. We were assigned to write a program that outputs the letter E made of asterisks with 5 down and 3 across as below:

```
*** 
* 
*** 
* 
***
```

The only requirement was to use nested-loops and if statements to get to our result. Below is my code. It works as intended, but I'm having trouble understanding why.

```
public class LetterE {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        final int NUM_ACROSS = 3; 
        final int NUM_DOWN = 5;        
        int row; 
        int column; 

        for (row = 1; row <= NUM_DOWN; row++) {
            if (row == 1 || row == 3 || row == NUM_DOWN)
                for (column = 1; column <= NUM_ACROSS; column++) {
                    if (column == 1 || column == NUM_ACROSS)
                        System.out.print("*");
                }
            System.out.print("*");
            System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Basically my issue comes with the System.out.print statements. I don't understand the relationship between my loops and the print statements. For example, the first print statement is inside the curly brace and taking it out causes an incorrect output. On top of that, I don't understand what the other print statements outside of that first curly brace are for and why they can't be inside the curly brace.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Trying my hardest to understand how this works, but I've been stuck on it for a while now.

Thank you very very much!

Comment: If you comment out all the print statements and add them one at a time starting with the *innermost* print statement, it may be easier (it was for me) to notice how it works. The innermost print statement is inside an `if` statement that checks and prints two `*`'s (`**`) if the `row` is `1`, `3`, or `5` (`NUM_DOWN`). Also, another key thing to notice is it is printing columns from *right* to *left*. So by this point the three rows of `**` are printed (the three horizontal rows that make the E)

Comment: Then, lastly, once this *innermost* `for`-loop completes, the `if`-branch exists and repeats the last iteration of the `for`-loop and prints `*` on all rows to make the left-most column of all `*`'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final int NUM_ACROSS = 3;
final int NUM_DOWN = 5;
int row;
int column;
```

I assume you know what the above code does, so I won't elaborate on that.

```
for (row = 1; row <= NUM_DOWN; row++) {
```

This code mean you want to execute the code inside the curly braces continuously as long as `row <= NUM_DOWN`. But before doing that, we assign `1` to `row` (this statement is executed only once). Each iteration ( = a full execution of the code inside the curly braces) `row++` will be executed.

So we start off with `row == 1`, then `row == 2`, `row == 3` ... until `row == 6`, at which point `row > NUM_DOWN`, because `NUM_DOWN == 5`.

If we would put all the values we have gotten for `row` in a list, the list would be equal to `{1,2,3,4,5,6}`, which contains 6 values. However, because the `for` loop is exited when `row == 6`, there are only `6 - 1 == 5` iterations.

Moving on:

```
if (row == 1 || row == 3 || row == NUM_DOWN){
```

Basically it means: if `row == 1` OR `row == 3` OR `row == 5`, then execute the code inside the curly braces. Otherwise, skip it.

```
for (column = 1; column <= NUM_ACROSS; column++) {
```

Basically the same as the other `for` loop, but just with different variables.

```
if (column == 1 || column == NUM_ACROSS)
```

Also the same as the `if` statement above, but again, with different parameters.

```
System.out.print("*");
```

This will print the `*` character once to the console *without* a newline ( = enter, basically).

The print statements that will be executed after this one will *append* another character to the already written characters, so your output will first look like this after the first iteration:

```
*
```

Then it will look like this after the third (in the second, `column` is equal to 2, so `column == 1 || column == NUM_ACROSS` is false and thus the code inside is not executed):

```
**
```

Then the loop is exited, and the other `print` statement is executed.

```
***
```

A space is also appended, but it is not visible because... well, it is a space :P

The `println` function is essentialy the same as `print` but it also appends the *escape sequence* `\n`. This escape sequence, called a newline, is like hitting enter on your keyboard: it starts a new line.

The next iteration, the code within the first `if` statement is skipped entirely, so we jump straight to the second `print` function. Now our output looks like this:

```
***
*
```

If we repeat the process, we will get:

```
***
*
***
```

.

```
***
*
***
*
```

.

```
***
*
***
*
***
```

---

Onto "optimizing" the program, because there is actually quite a lot of redundant code here:

```
int row; 
int column;
```

Just put it inside the `for` statements like this:

```
for (int row = 1; row <= NUM_DOWN; row++) {
```

It is shorter and a bit more readable ;)

```
if (row == 1 || row == 3 || row == NUM_DOWN){
```

This one is a bit odd, because on one hand, declaring NUM_DOWN makes it easier to change the height if you want to, but on the other hand, you have to edit the constants `1` and `3` manually then either way.
Let's go with the somewhat more adaptable way:

```
if (row == 1 || row == NUM_DOWN / 2 + 1 || row == NUM_DOWN) {
```

Integers are always rounded down, so `5 / 2 == 2`. The letter may look a bit odd when NUM_DOWN is even, but whatever.

```
for (int column = 1; column <= NUM_ACROSS; column++)
    if (column == 1 || column == NUM_ACROSS)
```

Well, this is just a strange section of code: we would be better of starting off with `column = 2` (`2` because we will print another asterisk below) and scrapping the `if` statement entirely (the loop will be executed for the values `2` and `3`, so 2 elements total --> 2 asterisks).

```
System.out.print(" ");
```

Since we can't read it, we can as well remove it altogether

```
System.out.println("*");
```

Again, it is shorter and it pretty much does the same thing.

```
System.exit(0);
```

Hmmm... It is not really needed, because your program returns 0 by default anyways.

The final program looks like this:

```
public class LetterE {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        final int NUM_ACROSS = 3; 
        final int NUM_DOWN = 5;        

        for (int row = 1; row <= NUM_DOWN; row++) {
            if (row == 1 || row == NUM_DOWN / 2 + 1 || row == NUM_DOWN)
                for (int column = 2; column <= NUM_ACROSS; column++)
                    System.out.print("*");
            System.out.println("*");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't begin to tell you how grateful I am for this. Not only did you make me realize how the loop works, but you helped me see redundancy. Unfortunately my professor gave us a "template" (a file partially coded without the loops but includes some other bits) so I don't want to change his code - but I actually completely understand what you did and that's awesome to me. Thank you very very very much!

Comment: I'm always glad to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. I replaced inner loop print to '#' just to give you idea how it works.. The inner loop is to print additional * required for 3 lines (top, middle, and bottom).  Outer System.out is by default we need * in each line and System.out.println is to move to next line. I moved the inner for loop in {} to make it more readable.

```
public class LetterE {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        final int NUM_ACROSS = 3; 
        final int NUM_DOWN = 5;        
        int row; 
        int column; 

        for (row = 1; row <= NUM_DOWN; row++) {
            if (row == 1 || row == 3 || row == NUM_DOWN){
                for (column = 1; column <= NUM_ACROSS; column++) {
                    if (column == 1 || column == NUM_ACROSS)
                        System.out.print("L");
                }
            }
            System.out.print("*");
            System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LetterE {
    public static void main(String[] args) {     
        int row; 
        int column; 
        for (row = 1; row <= 5; row++) { //final int NUM_DOWN = 5
            if (row == 1 || row == 3 || row == 5) {
                for (column = 1; column <= 3; column++) {//final int NUM_ACROSS = 3
                    if (column == 1 || column == 3)
                        System.out.print("*");
                }               
            }
            System.out.print("*");
            System.out.print("\n");      
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Look at my code. 
I have added another bracket for if loop for making it easier to you.

following code prints 1 `*` for 5 rows.

```
for (row = 1; row <= 5; row++) {
    System.out.print("*");
    System.out.print("\n"); 
}

output: 
row1: 1  = *
row2: 1  = *
row3: 1  = *
row4: 1  = *   
row5: 1  = *
```

Inside this for loop there is another for loop with if condition

```
if (row == 1 || row == 3 || row == 5) {
    for (column = 1; column <= 3; column++) {//final int NUM_ACROSS = 3
        if (column == 1 || column == 3)
        System.out.print("*");
    }               
 }
```

This loop prints another 2 `*` for row **1,3,5**
So, total no of `*` for

```
row1: 1 + 2 = ***
row2: 1     = *
row3: 1 + 2 = ***
row4: 1     = *
row5: 1 + 2 = ***
```

Hope that it will help you to understand.